# kendo ui grid date column - control the format of date sent by filter operation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do we control the format of date sent to the server as a result of applying a **Date Filter** to a grid column. For example, I have following View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#request-grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
        ...
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        CreatedOn: { type: "date" },
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
         },
        columns: [{
            field: "Id", title: "Id", width: 20
        }, {
            field: "CreatedOn", title: "Created On", width: 75, format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
        }, {
            command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: 200
        }],
    });

</script>
```

With when I try to filter the Date Column (CreatedOn), I see that the parameter is sent in format

**Wed Mar 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**.

How do I control the format of date that is being sent to server as a result of applying a **Date filter** on grid column.

I have already followed the procedure of setting culture as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582287/kendo-ui-grid-datasource-filter-date-format). Here is how I configured in the Layout page.

```
kendo.timezones.js and kendo.culture.en-IN.js included through bundle

<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("en-IN");
</script>
```

Any advice please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if chaging the culture is not doing the work. Then the function that you need to use is called [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) under the dataSource.transport configuration.

Comment: Yes, I did figure that out after putting some efforts going through documentation. But then it has to be done for every where I am using a date field. I was hoping for some kind of hooking up, which would then post all date fields in the format required for my asp.net MVC controller. Nevertheless, your answer solves the issue, but I would wait for some time, in case there is a better approach, before marking your response as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently fighting the same issue and for me the simplest way was to override the Date object toString method. I did it this way:

```
Date.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.getFullYear() + "-" + (this.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + this.getDate() + " " + this.getHours() + ":" + this.getMinutes() + ":" + this.getSeconds();
}
```